# Does a router that only has one connection to a switch with four connection have three interfaces in total?

Tags: routing, switch

Let us say that we have a router in a network. This router is in turn connected to only one network switch. Does it mean that this router has one interface or not only one but also the connections that the switch has?[image]

In this visualization. R1 has one interface m0, but with the switch, does it also have the other interfaces m1,m2 and m3?

Comment: The switch has 4. The router has 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The router has one physical interface that is connected to the switch.

The router *may* have multiple logical connections (sub-interfaces) that use the same physical interface.  That depends on the configuration of the router and switch.

Comment: I think it should be something like "The router has one physical interface that is connected to the *subnet* or "LAN"." I.e., from the point of the router there is a single LAN with multiple systems on it. Whether or not there is a switch is irrelevant to him.

Comment: @effenok There may be multiple virtual networks (VLANs) and there may even be multiple subnets on a single VLAN (rare)